# Programmatically click on a non-button element using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to programmatically click on a non-button element using javascript? Or is it atleast possible in browsers like Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Believe it or not, for a fairly basic click, you can just call `click` on it (but more below): [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/AxIbuxUb/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/AxIbuxUb/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Artificial Click</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">xxxxxxx</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
      foo.addEventListener("click", function() {
        display("Clicked");
      }, false);
      setTimeout(function() {
        display("Artificial click:");
        foo.click(); // <==================== The artificial click
      }, 500);
      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also create the relevant type of `Event` object and use [`dispatchEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-EventTarget-dispatchEvent) to send it to the element:

```
var e = new MouseEvent("click", {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});
foo.dispatchEvent(e);
```

This gives you the opportunity to do things like set other information (the typical `pageX` and `pageY`, for instance) on the event you're simulating.

More about the various event object types in [Section 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-module) of the DOM Events spec.

Comment: What about other built-in event types?

Comment: @Givi: See [Section 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-module) of the DOM Events spec.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `HTMLElementObject.click()`

Something like `document.getElementById('div1').click()`

See [more](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Or in jQuery ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)) to click on a non-button element

```
$( "#nonButton" ).click();
```

or to listen for a click on that non-button element

```
$("#nonButton").on("click", doSomething);
```

Comment: jQuery-only answers to non-jQuery questions are not useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementById("nonButton").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#front-chat-container div[role]')[0].click()
```

worked for me - to click a div element.