# Javascript - onkeyup, onclick and onfocus events are not getting fired automatically through Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, onkeyup, onfocus

I am automating a external web application(I can't change the code of external web app). I am able to set the value to the text box programmatically, but onkeyup, onclick and onfocus events are not getting fired automatically. This is code of text box.

```
 <input type="text" style="WIDTH: 145px" onfocus="doComboFocus(this)" 
 onkeyup="doComboSearch(this);enableAccountSearchForm();" 
 onclick=javascript:resetAccountSearchForm(); size=30 
 name=selectedAccountsNarrowSearch />
```

I have also try this.

```
selectedAccountsNarrowSearch.fireEvent("onclick");
```

doesn't get any help.

Working with Internet Explorer - 8

Please help me to fix this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What you trying to achieve? trigger event handlers cross-browser? if so, fireEvent only works in IE.

Comment: Look at [Programmatically click on a non-button element using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20871005/2029693), [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) and [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FCreating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: ok.thanks. i am trying to automate one web application, once i will enter some data into this text box manually it sortlist the values based on entered value and give me one value. but if i am setting the value programmtically then those events are not getting fired... i hope you have got some idea now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the event attribute content in double quotes.

```
<input type="text" style="WIDTH: 145px" onfocus="doComboFocus(this)"   onkeyup="doComboSearch(this);enableAccountSearchForm();" onclick="resetAccountSearchForm();" size="30" name="selectedAccountsNarrowSearch" />
```

The 'javascript:' in the onclick attribute might also be causing a problem.

Comment: double quotes is there, i want to fire these event through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your attribute in quotation marks (single or double).

```
<input type="text" style="WIDTH: 145px" onfocus="doComboFocus(this)"
 onkeyup="doComboSearch(this);enableAccountSearchForm();"
 onclick="javascript:resetAccountSearchForm();" size="30"
 name="selectedAccountsNarrowSearch" />
```